# Using class << self in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to understand the underlying mechanism behind Ruby's "class << self".
I understand how to use this and I know that this is a singleton-class definition, but I'd like to really understand how it works.

Here's an example:

```
class Klass
  puts "#{self}" #=> Klass
  class << self
    puts "#{self}" #=> #<Class:Klass>
  end
end

puts Klass.class #=> Class
puts Klass.singleton_class #=> #<Class:Klass>
```

Why do these statements output what they output? What's the difference between `Class` and `Class:Klass`, class and singleton_class??

Comment: Try http://www.devalot.com/articles/2008/09/ruby-singleton

Answer (score 0):

```
irb>
irb>
irb> class FightClub; def rule_1; 'You do not talk about FIGHT CLUB.'; end; end
=> nil
irb> club1=FightClub.new
=> #<FightClub:0x007fb4240c48d0>
irb> club2=FightClub.new
=> #<FightClub:0x007fb42394b770>
irb>
irb>
irb> def club2.rule_2; rule_1; end
=> nil
irb> club1.rule_1
=> "You do not talk about FIGHT CLUB."
irb> club1.rule_2
NoMethodError: undefined method `rule_2' for #<FightClub:0x007fb4240c48d0>
from (pry):6:in `__pry__'
irb>
irb> club2.rule_1
=> "You do not talk about FIGHT CLUB."
irb> club2.rule_2
=> "You do not talk about FIGHT CLUB."
irb>
```

Simple so far..

```
irb>
irb> club1.class.__id__ # FightClub
=> 70205838357120
irb> club2.class.__id__ # FightClub
=> 70205838357120
irb>
irb>
irb> club2.singleton_class # eigenclass of this instance
=> #<Class:#<FightClub:0x007fb42394b770>>
irb> club1.singleton_class
=> #<Class:#<FightClub:0x007fb4240c48d0>>
irb> club1.class.__id__ == club2.class.__id__
=> true
irb> club1.singleton_class.__id__ == club2.singleton_class.__id__
=> false
irb> club1.singleton_class.superclass.__id__ == 
irb*          club2.singleton_class.superclass.__id__ # 70205838357120
=> true
irb>
irb>
irb> club1.singleton_class.instance_methods.select{|m| m.to_s.start_with?('rule')}
=> [:rule_1]
irb> club2.singleton_class.instance_methods.select{|m| m.to_s.start_with?('rule')}
=> [:rule_2, :rule_1]
irb>
irb> club1.singleton_methods
=> []
irb> club2.singleton_methods
=> [:rule_2]
irb>
```

In case it's not clear already:

- `singleton_class` is the [eigenclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclass#In_Ruby) of an instance. Here is a good [explanation of eigenclass](http://madebydna.com/all/code/2011/06/24/eigenclasses-demystified.html).
- any instance methods (`rule_2` in this example) are `singleton_methods` and are created on the eighenclass.
- `superclass` of all eigenclasses is the same (and is = instance.class).
- ***Opinion***: So in reality `Class` instance representing class of `any_ruby_object` is actually the `any_ruby_object.singleton_class` and not `any_ruby_object.class`

Irrelevant but just to make it confusing:

```
irb> club2.methods.select{ |m| m.to_s.start_with?('rule') }
=> [:rule_2, :rule_1]
irb> club1.methods.select{ |m| m.to_s.start_with?('rule') }
=> [:rule_1]
irb>
```

Comment: If you removed all that IRB noise, the code would read much better.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton Classes are a special class that only exist for that instance of the class, as even class definitions are objects, another term for them is eigenclasses. One use is to define "class level methods" or "class level instance variables" (which are different to class variables) that are only available to class instances that define them. Another way to think of the eigenclass is that it's the instance of the class, because, as we know, everything in ruby is an object.

Here's a post by Andrea Singh that I've read numerous times to try and understand. It does a pretty good job of visualising the class method dispatch via the eigenclass:

http://madebydna.com/all/code/2011/06/24/eigenclasses-demystified.html

To be honest, It's a bit too meta to to explain on stack overflow, I think you're right to try and understand by trying examples. Just try to remember that it's <strike>elephants</strike> objects all the way down, until you reach <strike>the Turtle</strike> BasicObject!

Answer (score -1):

`#<Class:Klass>` and `Class` are different instances of the same class `Class`.

Comment: @Stefan A singleton class is a class. `Klass.singleton_class.class
# => Class`.

Comment: Thanks, @sawa, but is the difference between them?

Comment: @Sergey As I wrote, they are different instances. Just like `1` is not `2`, so are they.